# Data Mining Using dictionaries in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

with open(user_input_file_name, "r") as data_file: 
       header = data_file.readline()
       raw_data = data_file.readlines()
       for element in raw_data: 
           element = element.strip()
           useful_data.append(element)

```
    element = element.split(",")
    volume_list.append([element[0], float(element[5])])
    high_list.append([element[0], float(element[2])])
    low_list.append([element[0] ,float(element[3])])
```

data_file.close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use `Pandas` library for that purposes. It will out of the box solve that problem and many other problems in the future.

```
for element in useful_data: 
    year = element[0:4]
    month = element[5:7]
    date = element[8:10]
    trading_data = element[11:]

   try:
       main_dict[(int(year), int(month))].update({int(date):[trading_data]})
   except KeyError:
       main_dict[(int(year), int(month))] = {}
       main_dict[(int(year), int(month))].update({int(date):[trading_data]})
```

Comment: I notice that Pandas need to be installed first. Is there a way that does not need to install other libraries to fix the problem? I am using python 3.5

Comment: You didn't write copyt of inner_dict to the main_dict, you write only the ref to the same inner_dict to all the keys for main_dict. And when you cnahge inner_dict it changes for all the main_dict keys